# Android get Package name from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, package

I have an activity name from a third party application

```
"com.example.packagename.MainActivity"
```

How can I retrieve programmatically the package name of this third party application?

PS: I am not even sure this is an Activity. It could be a wrong string.

Comment: what do you mean by retrieving the package name? The Package name of the application or the class that string represents?

Comment: The package name of the application (I edit my qyestion)

Comment: You can use `PackageManager` for such thing. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#public-methods

Comment: I actually get a string name from an xml. Then, from this string I want to check if I can get the package name (but I am not sure the application exists)

Comment: there is no such way to do that, you know only activity name, but this activity can contain in multiple application, so it will be difficult for you to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the package name from an external app:

```
private String getExternalPackageName(String appname) {
    PackageManager pm = thisActivity.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> aList = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    String aName = "";
    for (ApplicationInfo appi : aList) {
        String n = (String)pm.getApplicationLabel(appi);

        if (n.toUpperCase().contains(appname)) {
            aName = appi.packageName;
        }
     }
     return aName;
}
```

be sure to call this function with appname => uppercase